# Trouble accessing JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sails.js

The data looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    "passports": [
      {
        "identifier": "2238006043",
        "protocol": "oauth",
        "tokens": {
          "token": "2238006043-fACsU7gVtpZnkuerodfsfdsfsdfdffsfOck1R9Z",
          "tokenSecret": "BQN25aRkJcyES3yWFCa7sSpq212PKbB52Mplxpg58hICs"
        },
        "provider": "twitter",
        "user": "54e8bca1513ab1841ab6da01",
        "createdAt": "2015-02-21T17:13:05.371Z",
        "updatedAt": "2015-02-21T17:13:05.371Z",
        "id": "54e8bca1513ab1841ab6da02"
      }
    ],
    "username": "myUsername",
    "createdAt": "2015-02-21T17:13:05.362Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-02-21T17:13:05.362Z",
    "id": "54e8bca1513ab1841ab6da01"
  },
```

And I'm trying to output something from passports like this:

```
console.log(util.inspect(res.passports[0].identifier, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));
```

res is the JSON object containing the data show below.

Comment: `res[0].passports[0]...` maybe

Answer (score 2):

try

```
console.log(util.inspect(res[0].passports[0].identifier, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));
```

it looks like `res` is an array

Answer (score 0):

The res JSON objects contains a list of items. thats why its not giving any value.
Please try this .

```
console.log(util.inspect(res[0].passports[0].identifier, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));
```